# How to download .zip in the Zend framework?

Tags: php

I am using an existing application and I am only able to download .pdf and .ppt files.

I am using Zend 1.11-6

Where would I find the setting to change which files are allowed to be downloaded.

Comment: Provide more details on how/where/what that download is. There's no obvious connection from "Zend" to "download PDF".

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with Zend Framework.  But...

In PHP when you want to download a file to the server, do a [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with a [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as the "data" parameter.